# Does vitamin D form crystals in the blood with calcium and magnesium?

Tags: human-biology, physiology, pharmacology

I read on a vitamin-D product (2000NE) that I should not use calcium and magnesium with it, because it can result crystal formation in the blood. I googled, but find anything about this. Is it true?

(Somehow I doubt it, but I don't know the exact mechanism how vitamin-D works by building bones. Afaik. there are osteoblasts and osteoclasts which constantly build and degrade the Ca-Mg-PO<sub>4</sub> depos, and I assume vitamin-D is just a cofactor of an enzyme or it is required to produce a hormone. I never heard of Ca/Mg - vitamin-D cross-reactions...)

Comment: Since vitamin D leads to the absorption of calcium, it can lead to hypercalcemia and calcium precipitation! This is true specially in patients with hyperphosphatemia (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2486454/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vitamin D does not bind to Calcium. It is a pre-hormone which is converted to calcitriol. Calcitriol has an intracellular receptor ([VDR](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/7421)) that, as a heterodimer with Retinoid-X receptor, regulates gene expression.

I guess the "should not be had together" is because of possible over-absorption of Calcium. There are commercially available supplements (e.g. [1](http://www.jamiesonvitamins.com/node/19), [2](http://www.hollandandbarrett.com/shop/product/holland-barrett-calcium-and-magnesium-with-vitamin-d-tablets-60016154)) that have Vit-D + Ca + Mg.

Comment: Additionally both are present in milk, if I remember correctly.

Comment: The exact words were "it forms crystals in the blood with calcium or magnesium" (in Hungarian ofc.). I guess it was just a bad joke of a frustrated worker, I don't know...